# Active record querying with store_accesors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a database where I need to do a search on specific record that has a certain output.  What is making this tricky for me is that these values are found in a 'store_accessor' and therefore they aren't always there.

For instance if I run `Team.last.team_configuration`, I get this value below, and what I need are only teams that have a specific setting.

```
<TeamConfiguration:0x00007123456987> {
        :id => 8,
  :owner_id => 6,
:team_type => "football",
  :settings => {
      "disable_coach_add" => false,
    "delink_players_at_18" => true
},
      :type => "TeamConfiguration"
```

}

My thoughts have been something around these lines, but i keep getting `undefined method 'settings' for team_configuration:Symbol`

```
Team.where(:team_configuration.settings['delink_players_at_18'])
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong in this instance? I think because there are two separations from the main source it has been causing me some issues.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Join configurations: `Team.join(:team_configurations).where(:team_configuration => { : team_type => "football" })`. But if `settings` data persisted as serialized string then I am afraid you have to search it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is way store_accesors works, look what documentation says:

> Store gives you a thin wrapper around serialize for the purpose of
>   storing hashes in a single column. It's like a simple key/value store
>   baked into your record **when you don't care about being able to query
>   that store outside the context of a single record**.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

So a posible solution could be to search by that column, converting a previously hash of what you want to string.

```
Team.where(team_configuration: data.to_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a postgres database and the `TeamConfiguration#settings` column is serialized as jsonb column you can get at this with [postgres json operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html):

```rb
Team.joins(:team_configurations)
  .where("team_configurations.settings @> '{\"delink_players_at_18\": true}'")
```